# print the half right pyramid abcd pattern using loop in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

```
 A
 AB
 ABC
 ABCD
 ABCDE

read -p "Enter rows:" rows
for((i=1; i<=rows; i++))
do
for((j=1; j<=i; j++))
do
echo -n 'a'   
done
echo
done
```

not able to print the above pattern uses for loop but not getting how to print the abcd pattern.

Comment: Where do you print b, c and d  in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use two `printf`s to convert ASCII values to characters:

```sh
read -p "Enter rows:" rows
for ((i=1; i<=rows; i++)); do
  for ((j=1; j<=i; j++)); do
    printf "\x$(printf %x $((64+j)))"
  done
  echo
done
```

---

If you want to stay with `echo -n` you could use an array initialized with all letters and reference it by index:

```sh
abc=({A..Z})
read -p "Enter rows:" rows
for ((i=1; i<=rows; i++)); do
  for ((j=0; j<i; j++)); do
    echo -n ${abc[j]}
  done
  echo
done
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for((i=1; i<=rows; i++))
do
for((j=1; j<=i; j++))
do
printf '%x' $(expr 96 + $j) | xxd -p -r
done
echo
done
```

I've converted ascii 97-->'a' to hex format and than decoded to that char value.

So what is happening here:

```
 printf '%x' $(expr 96 + $j)
```

will print the numbers like

```
61
6162
616263
61626364
```

Now we know that `\x61` --> 'a'. We want to convert this hex `\x61` to a char. So by using `-r` we are telling `xxd` to convert it from hex to ascii and by using `-p` we are telling `xxd` that out hex is a continous string not like `x61x62x63` but `616263`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you little bit explain me use of | xxd -p -r . i understand that xxd is for conversion of number into hexadecimal but the use of -p -r  in it can you explain little bit @Vaibhav.c

Answer (score -1):

`bash` parameter expansions comprise the `${parameter:offset:length}` substring expansion:

```sh
$ str="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
$ read -p "Enter rows:" rows
Enter rows:5
$ for (( i = 1; i <= rows; i++ )); do echo "${str:0:i}"; done
A
AB
ABC
ABCD
ABCDE
```

Note: of course if you enter a value greater than 26 the extra output lines will be truncated to 26 characters.

Note: instead of assigning `str` manually you can compute it with:

```sh
$ arr=({A..Z}); str="${arr[*]}"; str="${str// }"
$ echo "$str"
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

This uses brace expansion `{A..Z}` to construct the array `arr` of uppercase letters, and pattern substitution `${str// }` to remove the intermediate spaces in the expansion of the array `${arr[*]}`. This is handy and less error prone. If you would like to add lower case letters and digits:

```sh
$ arr=({A..Z} {a..z} {0..9}); str="${arr[*]}"; str="${str// }"
$ echo "$str"
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

Comment: str="${arr[*]}"; can you tell me why you add this while manually entering the string array as for spaces you do str="${str// }" got that and also arr=({A..Z}); for storing A TO Z  but able to get the use of str="${arr[*]}";

Comment: @RitwikRudra it is not `${arr[]}` but `${arr[*]}` which expands as the full content of the array, as one single word, and where the elements are separated by a space (in our case). This is a way to transform an array in a text string. And as the solution I propose uses substring substitutions this transformation is needed.

Comment: @F.Hauri Why do you mention forks? There are no forks here, just plain bash built-ins. And note that nested bash loops are fine in simple examples like this but as soon as the number of iterations increases the poor performance tends to become an issue. Note also that what you suggest will produce very strange results with values of `rows` larger than 26. It would probably be safer to sanitize it first.

Comment: @F.Hauri By the way, is it you who down-voted the question and all answers? If yes can you please explain why?